# Learning Java 5 with Java 7

Tags: java, java-7, java-5

I am studying a book -with a course- that is using Java 5.0 (1.5) 
And my machine has a Java 7 version (1.7.0_65)
Would this cause me any type of syntax headache or slow my pace by any means? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not install java 5 on that machine?

Comment: Time for a new book.

Comment: You'll, or rather the book, will basically be missing some things like `<>`, `try(with resources)`, `for(each)`, and `String`s in `switch`es.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java is always very careful about being backward-compatible. So if you use a newer version of the JDK to program, while writing code in an older syntax, that should be no problem in general.

Comment: Wasn't some string stuff taken out of 1.4 and put back into 1.5? I'm not a java pro so I can't quote chapter and verse but I'm sure this bit me once or twice.

Comment: @Poldie No, I don't think so. If you write 1.4 code with JDK 5, you won't have issues.

Comment: @peter.petrov: That's not true. Java 5 introduced e.g. the new key word "enum", meaning that old code using this word as a variable name won't compile with Java 5.

Comment: @jarnbjo I wrote and meant in general; there could be a few insignificant exceptions, of course.

Answer (score 0):

It should be ok. Generics syntax changed a bit.

In Java 5:

```
List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>;
```

In Java 7:

```
List<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
```

Of course, Java 5 generics syntax is still accepted in Java 7.

Answer (score 0):

Everything you can do in Java 5, you can do it exactly the same way in Java 7 since Java after version 5 is intentionally retrocompatible.. The converse is not true and you'd be better off studiying Java 8 directly, since it's the new version.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any problem, as java is a language that deal with compatible very well. And it is very stable. The language has few changes since Java 5.
Go ahead, good luck!